# Executing stored procedure with ODB ORM

Tags: c++, sql-server, stored-procedures, orm, odb

There is a procedure stored on Microsoft SQL Server. Procedure can return a value.
How can I execute stored procedure from MS SQL Server Database with ODB ORM and fetch value returned by this procedure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a native view for that. See Chapter 10, "Views" in the ODB manual for details.

Comment: The main problem is that ODB prepends "WHERE" statement to native SQL query string if this statement is not begins with "FROM", "WHERE", etc. For example ODB transforms query "EXEC MyStoreProcedure param1, param2" to "WHERE EXEC MyStoreProcedure param1, param2").
I modyfied libodb-mssql-2.3.0 library. I added conditions`s.compare (0, (n = 4), "EXEC") == 0 ||s.compare (0, (n = 4), "exec") == 0)`  function check_prefix in file query.cxx.

Is there any solution to call stored procedure without modifying the source code of ODB library?

Answer (score 0):

Correct solution for calling stored procedure is the following

```
#pragma db view query("exec MyStoredProc (?);")
struct StoredProc
{
    int Result;
    std::string Comment;
};


.
.
.


typedef odb::result<StoredProc> Result;
typedef odb::query<StoredProc>  Query;

.
.
.

Result r( db.query<StoredProc>( Query::_val(param1) + ", "
        + Query::_val(param2) ) ) );
```